# encoding url to short unique file name

Tags: python

I want to save html to a file based on the url.

to get unique name to url I am using uuid.

```
>>> url = "https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=-koUWPf4HqzT8ge2g6HoBg&gws_rd=ssl"
>>> uuidstring = str(uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, url))
```

but i want to further shorten the name. Is there any way to shorten string to unique small string.

I tried base64 but I could not figure out.

```
>>> uuid.UUID(uuidstring).bytes.encode('base64').rstrip('=\n').replace('/', '_')
>>> AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

linked question: [Convert UUID 32-character hex string into a "YouTube-style" short id and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270852/convert-uuid-32-character-hex-string-into-a-youtube-style-short-id-and-back)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `base64` module like this, it can handle binary data, then perform the decoding as `ascii` (will work because base64 is ascii).

```
import uuid,base64

url = "https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=-koUWPf4HqzT8ge2g6HoBg&gws_rd=ssl"
uuidstring = str(uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, url))
z=base64.encodebytes(uuid.UUID(uuidstring).bytes).decode("ascii").rstrip('=\n').replace('/', '_')
print(z)
```

result:

```
pvEA9qOdX8COYyJf8zgzRA
```

Comment: is `.replace('/', '_')` necessary?. will there any '/' be present while converting and uuidstring to base64?

Comment: it is possible to get `/` for instance with `base64.encodebytes(b"???")`. There's another char that you may need to strip: `+`. but with your string `a6f100f6-a39d-5fc0-8e63-225ff3383344` it is unlikely you're right, since you would need a lot of following 1 bits.

Comment: thanks. I will check for large data set and update accordingly.